# Populate a list view in on create android

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a listview on a screen called Leaderboard.xml I have been around loads of different sites and nobody seems to show a clear way of doing this (most seem to require some form of user input).

I have a database helper class which is below:

```
package com.example.deepseadiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ScoreDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Highscores";


    private OpenHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context dbContext;


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "name TEXT, " +
                        "score TEXT);";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.dbContext = ctx;
    }


    public DatabaseHelper open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new OpenHelper(dbContext);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    public boolean createUser(String name, String score) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("name", name);
        initialValues.put("score", score);

        return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues) > 0;
    }


    public boolean updateUsers(long rowId, String name, String score) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put("name", name);
        args.put("score", score);

        return mDb.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "_id=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }


    public void deleteAll() {
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }


    public void deleteRecord(long rowID) {
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_rowId=" + rowID, null);
    }


    public Cursor getdata(String table) 
    {
        return mDb.rawQuery("Select * from "+table+"", null);

    }

    public Cursor fetchAll(SQLiteDatabase db, String table){

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+table+"", null);
        return cursor;

    }


    public ArrayList<String[]> fetchScore(String name) throws SQLException {

        ArrayList<String[]> myArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        int pointer = 0;     

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "name",
                "score"}, "name LIKE '%" + name + "%'", null,
                    null, null, "score desc");


        int NameColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        int ScoreColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex("score");     


        if (mCursor != null){
           if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    myArray.add(new String[3]);
                    myArray.get(pointer)[0] = mCursor.getString(NameColumn);
                    myArray.get(pointer)[1] = mCursor.getString(ScoreColumn);
                    pointer++;
                } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
           } else {

               myArray.add(new String[3]);
               myArray.get(pointer)[0] = "NO RESULTS";
               myArray.get(pointer)[1] = "";
           }
        } 

        return myArray;

    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> selectAll() {


        ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();


        int counter = 0;

        Cursor cursor = this.mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id", "name", "score"}, null, null, null, null, "name desc");


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            results.add(new String[2]);
            results.get(counter)[0] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
            results.get(counter)[1] = cursor.getString(1).toString();
            results.get(counter)[2] = cursor.getString(2).toString();
            counter++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return results;
    }


    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

and the leaderboard.java:

```
package com.example.deepseadiver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Leaderboard extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout LeaderExit;

    String table = "Highscores";

    DatabaseHelper dbh;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.leaderboard);

            dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            dbh.open();


            LeaderExit = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Exit);


            LeaderExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Leaderboard.this.finish();
                }
            });
     }





}
```

the list view I am trying to populate has an id of lvItems and it is on the leaderboard.xml screen.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You are doing nothing with 'listItems' and 'adapter' and a ListView. So no this will not work.

Comment: Is it possible to do this every site seems to refer to methods in the helper class that I do not have

Comment: Of course that is possible. But if you do not even do the basic things which i mentioned you should not complain. Implement an adapter who uses listItems and set to your listview.